# How to get prediction labels with Tensorflow Serving Predict API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tfx

I have a keras classification model saved remotely, and I use [RESTful API](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest) to call the model on my site and make predictions. The JSON request is done as follows

URL:

```
POST https://my.site/models/v1:predict
```

JSON:

```
{"instances": [["...something useful to predict a label..."]]}
```

and what I obtain is of the form (one value for each label)

```
{
  "predictions": [
    [
      0.001
      0.832
      ...
      0.104
    ]
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to obtain also the label corresponding to each prediction probability? That is, to get something in the form

```
{
  "predictions": [
    [
      "label_1": 0.001
      "label_2": 0.832
      ...
      "label_n": 0.104
    ]
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "predictions": [
    [
      0.001
      0.832
      ...
      0.104
    ]
    [
      "label_1"
      "label_2"
      ...
      "label_n"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I read documentation about [specifying signatures](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#specifying_signatures_during_export) when exporting a model, which seems to be related to my question, but it is not very clear about what has to be done. Basically it consists of adding the argument `signatures` when saving the model:

```
@tf.function()
def my_predict(my_prediction_inputs):
    ...

my_signatures = my_predict.get_concrete_function(...)

tf.keras.models.save_model(model, path, signatures=my_signatures, ...)
```